# Error when transfering ERC20 from account to contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I'm getting the following error when trying to transfer an IERC20 token from an account to a contract:
`Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ds-math-sub-underflow -- Reason given: ds-math-sub-underflow.` (it fails at the `pair.transferFrom` line).

But if I try to transfer from account to account it works, it only fails when I try to transfer from an account to the contract:

```js
const PAIR = "0x397ff1542f962076d0bfe58ea045ffa2d347aca0";
const PAIR_WHALE = "0x7ac049b7d78bc930e463709ec5e77855a5dca4c4";

const pair = await IERC20.at(PAIR);
const myContract = await MyContract.deployed();
// const addr = accounts[0]; // Works!!!
const addr = myContract.address; // Fails with error above

let whaleBal = await pair.balanceOf(PAIR_WHALE);
await pair.approve(addr, whaleBal, { from: PAIR_WHALE });
await pair.transferFrom(PAIR_WHALE, addr, whaleBal);
```

---

My setup for running this:

- mainnet fork with infura + ganache
- `PAIR` is the address from the `USDC-WETH` pair from sushiswap
- `PAIR_WHALE` unlocked via ganache
- The snippet of code above is from a test file I run with `truffle test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pair.approve(addr, whaleBal, { from: PAIR_WHALE });
```

On this line, the `PAIR_WHALE` (transaction sender) approves the **contract address** (the value of `addr`) to spend their tokens.

```
pair.transferFrom(PAIR_WHALE, addr, whaleBal)
```

But on this line, the **`accounts[0]`** (the default transaction sender) is trying to spend the `PAIR_WHALE`'s tokens. But the `accounts[0]` is not approved to do this.

When you assigned the value of `accounts[0]` to `addr` in the commented line, the `PAIR_WHALE` effectively approved the `accounts[0]` to spend their tokens, which caused the `transferFrom()` function to pass.

---

You cannot send a transaction on behalf of the contract address, as its private key is unknown.

But if you want to transfer the `PAIR_WHALE` tokens to the contract address, you can simply invoke the `transfer()` function from the `PAIR_WHALE` address.

```
// transfers `whaleBal` of `pair` tokens
// from the `PAIR_WHALE` address
// to the `myContract.address` address
pair.transfer(myContract.address, whaleBal, {from: PAIR_WHALE});
```